# How to keep gizmos visible when moving objects?

Tags: interface, gizmo

I was wondering if it's possible to keep the axes gizmo visible while moving objects. I know it would be easier to learn was color is axis X and what color is Y, but having the gizmo visible would help and it would also help to visualize if we moving positive or negative along those axis.

Is there any reason for the gizmos to go away in the first place?

Hopefully there is a seting to prevent this.

[image: Gizmos]

PS: I'm talking when pressing "G" to move.

Answer (score 0):

You cropped the solution out of the posted image. Use the move tool.
[image]

Or you can enable the move tool overlay:

[image]

Comment: Susu I guess I wasn't clear enough. When I press "G" to move, those gizmos go away.